# Adoptable storage and nandroid backup - All apps included?

Tags: backup, adoptable-storage, nandroid

I have an SD card in internal storage mode (adoptable storage) and want to do a full backup of my device. In this mode the SD card has folders equivalent to /data/app, /data/data and /data/media. If I do a nandroid backup with TWRP, are any of these folders included in the backup?

In case they are not included: What would be the best way to do a full backup of my phone with all apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm that TWRP -- the latest version as of writing, at least -- recognizes, decrypts, backs up, and restores the contents of adoptable storage correctly. Note, though, that [just as it ignores `/data/media/`](https://twrp.me/faq/backupexclusions.html), it also ignores `/external_sd/media/`, so be sure to backup that folder manually.